# BMW E90: Coming Home automatically on darkness

Tags: bmw, obd-ii

I have a BMW E90 ( pre- facelift ) with light package . Currently my car is set so that the " Coming Home " function can by pressing the headlight flasher is switched off, press at ignition .
My question at this point is whether it is also possible simply to leave by encoding the light (assuming it was already dark when driving and accordingly ) until a few seconds after you complete the cars ? That would be a great functionality and the light would not only when you turn the ignition off and then turned on by the " headlight flash " again . Because someone knows advice? Many thanks!

---------- Deutsch ----------

ich habe einen BMW E90 (Vor-Facelift) mit Lichtpaket. Momentan ist mein Auto so eingestellt, dass sich die "Coming Home" Funktion durch Betätigen der Lichthupe bei ausgeschaltener Zündung betätigen lässt.

Meine Frage an dieser Stelle ist nun, ob es auch möglich ist durch Codieren das Licht einfach anzulassen (vorausgesetzt es war beim Fahren schon dunkel und entsprechend an), bis einige Sekunden nach dem Abschließen den Autos? Das wäre eine super Funktionalität und das Licht müsste nicht erst beim Ausschalten der Zündung aus- und danach durch die "Lichthupe" wieder eingeschalten werden. Weiß da jemand Rat? Vielen Dank!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for posting. As an aside, please don't worry about dual posting in Deutsch/English, as Stack Exchange is specifically English unless the specific site is situated for a different language.